# Abraham's Temptation: only a matter of Faith, or also of Hope?

Tags: faith, abraham, theological-virtues

[image: Caravaggio: The Sacrifice of Isaac (1603)]
Caravaggio: *The Sacrifice of Isaac* (1603)

In Genesis 22 we read that God tested (or "put to the test", or "tempted" - the Hebrew verb **נָסָה** [*nacah*] bears all these meanings) Abraham, saying to him: "Take now your son, your only son Isaac, whom you love, and go to the land of Moriah, and offer him there as a burnt offering [**עֹלָה** - *`olah*] on one of the mountains of which I shall tell you." ([Gen 22:2](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Genesis%2022:2&book=genesis&chapter=22&verse=2))

In the end, as we all know, God (or "the Lord’s angel") stopped Abraham, and provided a ram "caught in the bushes by its horns" in replacement of Isaac ([Gen 22:13](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Gen%2022:13&book=gen&chapter=22&verse=13)), and in the end the Lord (or "the Lord’s angel") praised Abraham "because you have done this and have not withheld your son, your only son" and renewed His promise to make hism "the father of a multitude of nations". ([Gen 22:15-18](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=Gen%2022:15-18&passage=gen%2022:15-18))

In the *Letter to the Hebrews*, Abraham stands out in the hall of fame of *People Commended for Their Faith*:

> <sup>17</sup> By faith Abraham, when he was tested, offered up Isaac.
> He had received the promises, yet he was ready to offer up his only
> son. <sup>18</sup> God had told him, “Through Isaac descendants will
> carry on your name,” <sup>19</sup> and he reasoned that God could even
> raise him from the dead, and in a sense he received him back from
> there. ([Heb 11:17-19](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=Hebrews%2011:17-19&passage=hebrews%2011:17-19)).

Paul, in his Letter to the Romans, seems to affirm that Abraham's justification is **through his faith only**:

> “Abraham believed God, and it was credited to him as righteousness.”
> ([Rom 4:3](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Rom%204:3&book=rom&chapter=4&verse=3); quot. from [Gen 15:6](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?book=Gen&chapter=15&verse=6))

Then Paul, though, only few verses on in the same passage, affirms:

> Against **hope** Abraham [he]  believed in **hope** with the result that he
> became *the father of many nations* [Gen 17:5](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?book=Gen&chapter=17&verse=5) according to the
> pronouncement, “*so will your descendants be* [as numerous as the
> stars in the sky - [Gen 15:5]](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?book=Gen&chapter=15&verse=5).” ([Rom 4:18](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Rom%204:18&book=rom&chapter=4&verse=18))

Based on this verse, the expression "[to hope against hope](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+hope+against+hope)" has become a common idiom, meaning something like "to continue to hope for something even though it seems unlikely to happen".

The original Greek expression translated by NET (and similarly by others) "Against hope [he] believed in hope", is παρ’ἐλπίδα ἐπ’ἐλπίδι ἐπίστευσεν (lit. "beyond hope, upon hope [he] believed"). "Against" is an improper translation of παρά.

**Was Abraham's hope something ultimately irrational? What did Abraham believe? What did he hope for?**

### Is faith really enough to explain Abraham's behaviour, or is it necessary to consider at least another "ingredient": hope?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124566/discussion-on-question-by-miguel-de-servet-abrahams-temptation-only-a-matter-o).

Comment: I have substantially edited the question. I **hope** that it is going to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Faith-Complete trust or confidence in someone or something. Hope-a feeling of expectation and desire or a certain thing to happen. A feeling of trust.

God deals with Abraham starting at Genesis 12 when He ask Abraham to go forth from your country and from your relatives to the land which I will show you. (Genesis 12:1). At vs4 Abraham does what God told him.

At Genesis 13:1, "So Abram went up from Egypt to Negev, he and his wife and all that belonged to him, and Lot with him." At Genesis 15:1, After these things the word of the Lord came to Abram in a vision saying, Do not fear, Abram, I am a shield to you; Your reward shall be very great. At Genesis 15:18 the Lord made aa covenant with Abram, saying, To your descendants I have given you this land etc.

The Lord God deals further with Abram and his wife Sarah at Genesis 16, Genesis 17, Genesis 18-22 and beyond. Of course Genesis 22 is the sacrifice of Abraham's only son Isaac.

What I'm saying is the fact that both "faith and hope" directed Abraham and his actions. At Hebrews 11 (which is known as the "faith" book) Abraham is the center piece starting at vs8. "By faith Abraham when he was called obeyed by going out to a place which he was to receive for an inheritance; and he went out, NOT KNOWING WHERE HE WAS GOING."

At vs17, "By faith Abraham, when he was tested, offered up Isaac; and he who had received the promises (plural) was offering up his only begotten son; vs18, it was he to whom it was said, In Isaac your descendants shall be called."

Hebrews 11:19, "He/Abraham considered that God is able to raise men even from the dead; from which he also received him back as a type." Going back to Romans 4 in which the Apostle Paul talks about Abraham in detail.

Romans 4:18, "In hope against hope he believed, in order that he might become a father of many nations, according to that which had been spoken, "So shall your descendants be."

Romans 4:19, "And without becoming weak in faith he contemplated his own body; now as good as dead since he was about a hundred years old, and the deadness of Sarah's womb." Vs21, "and being fully assured that what He/God had promised, He was able also to perform."

In short both faith and hope go hand in hand where God held Abraham's hand all through His dealings with him by giving him confidence.

Comment: Mr. Bond, (1) I am glad that you acknowledge that "faith and hope go hand in hand", in Abraham's response to God, since the beginning of Genesis 12, since Abraham's call. (2) Nevertheless, to speak of Hope as "a _feeling_ of expectation and desire or a certain thing to happen. A _feeling_ of trust" makes Hope appear as an "aspect" of Faith, and does not clarify why Hope is a distinct theological virtue.

Comment: @Miguel de Servet Please notice the definitions of both words and the "subtle" difference. Faith is complete trust in someone. In this case it is God. Hope is "hoping" your expectations of your faith in God will come to pass." Learning to trust God is a process and do you want to know why I personally trust God? Think about the statement I'm going to make. I know God answers prayers (whether the answer is yes or no) it's when "REALITY" proves God is right. Abraham learned to trust God from his past experiences where reality proved God to be right.   And yes, sometimes we will have doubts.

Comment: Mr. Bond Did Abraham have **faith** that God would spare his son Isaac? Yes or no? (Careful ...)

Comment: @MigueldeServet Yes! May I explain why I know the answer to your question is yes? Hebrews11:17, "By faith Abraham, when he was tested, offered up Isaac; and he who had received the promises (plural) was offering up his only begotten son; Vs18, it was he to whom it was said, "In Isaac your descendants shall be called." Vs19 He/Abraham considered that God is able to raise men even from the dead; from which he also received him back as a type." Notice it says, "promises" plural. One of those promises is that Sarah was to have a son even though they knew Sarah was to hold, yet what happened?

Comment: continued. Like I said, reality proved God to be right. Abraham believed God could raise Isaac "figuratively" from the deadness of Sarah's womb. Is this "careful" enough for you Miguel?

Comment: Mr. Bond, I fully agree that "One of those promises is that Sarah was to have a son even though they knew Sarah was to hold [too old - I guess]". The other one was, obviously that through Isaac, the "son of the promise", Abraham will become "the father of a multitude of nations" (Gen 17:5). As for Heb 11:17-19, some have interpreted this passage to mean that, if ever God had indeed required Isaac’s death, God would have returned Isaac to Abraham by way of resurrection. [continued]

Comment: [continuation] Having written, “Abraham believed God could raise Isaac **’figuratively’** from the deadness of Sarah's womb”, you don't seem one of them. So, as you have said yes to my previous yes/no question, let me put my question differently. Are you considering the possibility that Abraham trusted God to give him back Isaac through resurrection, **not “figuratively” but literally**, after letting him kill Isaac?

Comment: We can only go by what was written because we do not know the operation of one's mind especially regarding events that did not happen. The fact is that Abraham did not slay his son because God/the angel of the Lord stopped him at Genesis 22:11. What we know for sure is that God kept His word/promises. Is there some kind of point your trying to make in all of this?

Comment: Mr. Bond _Is there some kind of point your trying to make in all of this?_ Sure, and it should be obvious by now! I believe that faith is not enough to explain Abraham's behaviour, and it necessary to consider at least another "ingredient": hope! As for "we do not know the operation of one's mind especially regarding events that did not happen", obviously who wrote Hebrews 11:17-19 didn't seem to stop in front of this obvious limitation ... he even seemed to know what Abraham was reasoning (_logisamenos_) in his head!

Comment: BTW, there is no serious ground to infer that, at that initial stage of God's revelation, Abraham would even imagine the resurrection of the dead.